# Layout Input Fields with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3. I am trying to layout a group of input controls. When all is said and done, I want my controls to look like the following:

```
approximately [drop down  ][mi.]
from          [value1], [value2]
              p1        p2
```

`[mi.]` is supposed to be a `input-group-addon`. `[value1]` and `[value2]` are supposed to be textboxes. Finally, `p1` and `p2` are just styled hints. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-addon">approximately&nbsp;</div>
  <select class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-addon">mi.</div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">from&nbsp;</div>
  <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" />
  <div class="input-group-addon">,</div>
  <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" />
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="hint">p1</div>
  <div class="hint">p2</div>
</div>
```

This approach doesn't work though. The reason why is because the layout is row-based. While the input controls fill up the remaining space like I would want, they do not align with each other column wise. At the same time, when I use the bootstrap grid, the spacing gets all out of whack. Is there a way to create the layout I'm shooting for with Bootstrap? If so, how?

Comment: you mean like this? http://www.bootply.com/jUtrpuxTqE

Comment: @Sebsemillia not exactly. Once again, the input fields do not align properly.

Comment: Are they supposed to line up like [this example?](http://www.bootply.com/HkgdruLxBz)